# Project a Type to class object by filtering out attributes using linq to xml

Tags: xml, linq, soap-client

If i have a xml soap document and i want to get its data(element ) that are segmented by attributes, how do i filter out the attributes and convert the filter data into class.

```
public  class report
{     
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
}
```

Xml sample:

```
<Rows>
    <Row ref="h_0_0" inx="0" kind="h">
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_0">Vehicle Name</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_1">Date</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_2">Driver</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_3">Total Distance (GPS)</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_4"> Max Speed</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_5">Average Speed</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_6">Expected Fuel Avg (km/l)</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_7">Total Fuel</Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_8">Fuel Lost </Cell>
        <Cell ref="h_0_0_9">Location</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ref="i_0_0" inx="0" kind="i">
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_0">TP126</Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_1">22/04/2020</Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_2">Paul Obiero Owuor </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_3">170.4 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_4">19.2 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_5">7.7 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_6">2.8 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_7">0.0 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_8">0.0 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_9">Garsen</Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row ref="i_0_0" inx="1" kind="i">
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_0">TP113</Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_1">22/04/2020</Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_2">SALIM SAID ABOUD</Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_3">104.9 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_4">16.1 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_5">4.1 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_6">2.8 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_7">34.7 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_8">0.0 </Cell>
        <Cell ref="i_0_0_9">Garsen</Cell>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

what i want to accomplish

```
public void  FetchReport()
{
    var results =  reportServicebase.FetchReport(_ihandleID);
    List<RestHeavyConsumptionModel> heavylist = new List<RestHeavyConsumptionModel>();

    XElement doc = XElement.Parse(results.Result.ToString());

    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    doc1.LoadXml(results.Result.ToString());

    if(ReportStatus == "Done")
    {
        RestHeavyConsumptionModel heavy = new RestHeavyConsumptionModel();

        heavy.VehicleName = doc1.GetElementsByTagName("cell").

    } 
}
```

how can i make the results from the xml when calling the soapclient proxy so that it values(cell) will assigned to report objects .

Comment: I think, the first row contains definition of columns, so the expected result will be list of report for Kind `i`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

- Your XML is not standard, it contains some kind of header as first Row
- The Rows do not contain your actually required value. The read data need to be converted to your class `Report`.

### Read the XML data

I'm not sure if you already have created an XML reader for your non-standard data. If you'll be reading this data more often, or for other conversions, consider to separate your solution into several sub-solutions.

You have some source data, that represents a sequence of `Rows` in XML-format.

- Define a type that represents `Row`
- Get your original data: a file, a stream, a textreader, a string. This has XML-format
- Convert this original data into a `DataSet`
- Convert the `DataSet` to `IEnumerable<Row>`
- Convert `IEnumerable<Row>` into `IEnumerable<Report>`.

.

```
class Row // TODO: invent a proper name, something like CarRideData?
{
    public string VehicleName {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Driver {get; set;}
    ... // etc.
}
```

### Read your XML source data into DataSet

You didn't specify your exact source: is it a file? a string? Stream? Luckily class `DataSet` has methods for all these inputs. See: [Loading a DataSet from XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/loading-a-dataset-from-xml)

```
string xmlFileName = ...
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName);
```

Or if you have a Stream:

```
using (Stream stream = ...)
{
    dataSet.ReadXml(stream);
};
```

Similar for TextReader or String

### Convert DataSet to IEnumerable

I'll write the conversion methods as extension methods. This way you can use them as if it as a source for LINQ expressions. This has the advantage that if your source changes, for instance changes format, or from XML to CSV or a database, the other procedures don't have to change. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<Row> ToRows(this DataSet source)
{
    // TODO: decide what tho do if source == null

    // in small steps, of course you can take bigger steps if you want:
    IListSource listSource = dataSet;
    if (listSource.ContainsListCollection)
    {
        // the XML contains a collection
        IList list = listSource.GetList();

        // the List is expected to contain a sequence of Rows.
        // if you are certain about this, just Enumerable.Cast:
        return list.Cast<Row>();

        // alternative, if you think that there might be other types in the list,
        // use Enumerable.OfType, this will ignore all other types and return only
        // the Rows
        return list.OfType<Row>();
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: decide what to do if the source doesn't have the expected format
        // throw exception? return empty sequence?
        return IEnumerable.Empty<Row>();
    }
}
```

Nota Bene: the rows still contain your header! You can just `Skip(1)` to get to your proper collection of Rows. If this will be used on more locations, people might forget to remove the header element. If you are certain that no one needs the header, consider to Skip it in your method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Row> ToRows(this DataSet source)
{
    return source.GetList().Cast<Row>.Skip(1);
}
```

Usage:

```
string xmlFileName = ...
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName);
IEnumerable<Row> rows = dataSet.ToRows();
```

### Convert sequence of Rows to sequence of Report

Again as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Report> ToReports(this IEnumerable<Row> rows)
{
    // TODO: decide what to do if rows == null

    return rows.Select(row => new Report
    {
        VehicleName = row.VehicleName,
        DriverName = row.DriverName,
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string xmlFileName = ...
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName);
IEnumerable<Report> reports = dataSet.ToRows().ToReports();
```

### Optional improvement

If you will be reading Rows or Reports quite a lot, consider creating a procedure for these four lines:

```
IEnumerable<Row> ReadRows(string xmlFileName)
{
    string xmlFileName = ...
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName);
    return dataSet.ToRows();
}

IEnumerable<Report> ReadReports(string xmlFileName)
{
    return ReadRows(xmlFileName).ToReports();
}
```

Usage:

```
string xmlFileName = ...
IEnumerable<Report> reports = ReadReports(xmlFileName);
```

### Summary

Because you split up your problem into smaller conversions, these conversion will be highly reusable: if your source comes from a CSV file, or from a database, you can still use `ToReport`. If you want a different destination type, you can still use ReadXML and ToRows. If your source is not a fileName, but a Stream, or a String, only change ReadXml.

Because you created Extension methods of IEnumerable, usage can be intertwined with LINQ:

```
string xmlFileName = ...
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
IEnumerable<Report> todaysReports = ReadRows(xmlFileName)
     .Where(row => row.Date == today)
     .ToReports();
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help , i have been able to solve this , the xml is not standard because it is produced by a report generator that has many "report " format  . The idea is to go through all the rows element and add a new report class . Each element <cell> with the attribute "i_0_0_x" represent a new object and properties of the report class .